# A Riddle That I Don't Understand

Tags: riddle

> *A creature imagined,
>
>   with magic, they say;
>
>   A boat that you ride on,
>
>   when crossing a bay.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is...

> a **FAIRY/FERRY**
>
>  Fairy = magical creature of myth
>  Ferry = boat for going across a small body of water.

Comment: which is the answer?

Comment: someone is to blame, for what has gone wrong; a line on a map, the earth quakes along.

Comment: I would assume that the answer is intended to be given verbally, which is fine for these homonyms.

Comment: @NiasiaSanchez - "Fault".  Also, if this is the correct answer, you should give it a checkmark.